# Change Windows Tkinter after some time

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to switch between windows after some time, but I can't get my code to work.

My windows change only when I click on button. I tried to put lambda in my command, but that still didn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3
#import Tkinter as tk   # python
import datetime
TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
delta_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 5)
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, TimePage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Time Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(self.start_Counting()) )
        button1.pack()

    def start_Counting(self):
        global time_start
        time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
        return 'TimePage'

class TimePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        global delta_time
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is Time Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.time_exit = tk.StringVar()
        self.time_exit.set('%s' %datetime.datetime.now())
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text=self.time_exit, font=TITLE_FONT)
        label2.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

    def update_Page(self):
        global time_start, delta_time
        #print('Executou o atualizar')
        time_until = delta_time - (datetime.datetime.now() - time_start)
        self.time_exit.set('%s' %time_until)
        if time_until <= 0:
            self.controller.show_frame('StartPage') # Go to the start_page after 5 seconds
        self.after(1000, update_Page)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I improved formatting, but I believe this question may need more details about the exact error being encountered. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You never call `update_Page`. The first step would be to call that function. However, there's no need to repeatedly do calculations on datetime objects. Just calculate how many seconds in the future you need, and call `after` once.